# Applying a data group filter to a gauge's scale and range expressions

Tags: ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I am creating a series of gauges with which I'm trying to show how well groups are projecting the number of resource hours they consume each month. The scale of the gauge goes from 0 to a rounded up value of the **projected** hours, and the gauge needle points to the value of the **actual** hours used. The range is used to indicate actual is within 10% of the projected hours (green), between 10 to 30% (yellow), or more than 30% off (red). Some examples of gauges that were built individually:

[image]

The number of hours that each group projects and uses can vary greatly, as seen from the gauges. I have been able to apply a filter that makes it easy to set the gauge needle to point to the total actual hours for each group by simply changing the group name in the filter, but I can't get the sums of projected hours to filter for each group in the scale and range configurations. As a result, if I create a single gauge with a filter, copy that gauge, and then just change the group name in the filter for each new gauge, I can get the corresponding actual hours (i.e., where the needle points), but the scale defaults to the sum of projected hours for ALL of the groups:

[image]

Does anyone know of a way that I can apply the filter to the scale and range calculations other than actually specifying the group name in an already complex IIF expression? I have to create over 50 of these gauges, and it would be prohibitively time consuming to have to cut and paste every instance of the group name into every instance of these expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I needed to add a filter to the Gauge **Panel**. The first filter I created was applied to the Gauge **Data**. Once I created that second filter, I was able to use simple expressions to set the scale and range values, and then just change the group name in both filters for each gauge I created. Still a little more manual than I'd like, but substantially more manageable and scalable.